# how to space between components

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm trying to eliminate space between an icon and a label;
I've search on internet and try a lot but there is not way to find a solution for me!!
All I need is not having space between an icon and a text:
[image]

this is the code:

```
Label subTitle = new Label("nel cammin di nostra vita mi trovai in selva oscura");
Label stpIMG = null;
        
stpIMG = new Label();
stpIMG.setContentMode(ContentMode.HTML);
stpIMG.setValue("<img src=\"VAADIN/themes/valo/images/sprite_svg_all.svg#ristampa\">");
stpIMG.setWidth("30px");
stpIMG.setHeight("20px");

HorizontalLayout subTitleLayout=null;
        
subTitleLayout = new HorizontalLayout(stpIMG,subTitle);
subTitleLayout.setExpandRatio(stpIMG, 1);
subTitleLayout.setExpandRatio(subTitle, 2);
    
subTitleLayout.setWidth("650px");
subTitleLayout.setSpacing(false);

mainLayout.addComponents(subTitleLayout);
```

What I'm wrong?
thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `subTitleLayout.setExpandRatio(stpIMG, 1);`

`setExpandRatio` is telling the layout to expand the slot containing `stpIMG`.

Comment: but if I comment both line of setExpandRadio the result is that the text will be on the icon ; in other word you cannot see the n

Comment: I'm guessing that's because the image is actually larger than the 30px width you're giving to stpIMG.

Any particular reason you're using a Label for the image instead of an Image component?

Comment: because I haven't find how to set an image to a label on the same line; if I use subTitle.SetIcon it appears on two line;

Comment: The same way you're placing two Labels on the same line? In a HorizontalLayout that lays things out horizontally, i.e. in a line?

Comment: thanks a lot for your replay. I'm not able to undersand how to eliminate space between them, I've tried with setExpandRatio but I cannot dispose as I wish; I'm going to get crazy for that :)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue in this way:

public static HorizontalLayout BuildIconStampa(String... text) {

```
Label warnIMG = new Label();
warnIMG.setContentMode(ContentMode.HTML);


warnIMG.setValue("<img src=\"VAADIN/themes/valo/images/sprite_all2.svg#ristampa\">");
warnIMG.setWidth("30px");
warnIMG.setHeight("30px");


Label[] labels = new Label[text.length];
for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    Label body = new Label(text[i]);
    body.setSizeFull();
    body.setStyleName("bsr-gray");
    labels[i] = body;
}

VerticalLayout vl = new VerticalLayout(labels);
HorizontalLayout result = new HorizontalLayout(warnIMG, vl);
result.setSpacing(true);
result.setExpandRatio(vl, 1);
return result;
```

}